# Read the extended attributes for a file in SELinux

Tags: linux, selinux, xattr

I want to read the capabilities of a file in linux.

I want answer something like this with complete details...

```
/path/to/file: uid:0 gid:2000 mode:100750 capability:40 selinux:u:object_r:runas_exec:s0
0x40 = 64 decimal
```

I tried `ls -l`, `getfattr`, `xattr` but nothing worked...

After applying the selinux attribute values, how can i read it?

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried ls with -Z option.

In SE Linux many of the common commands(eg ls, cp, mv) have been modified to include options (eg. -Z) to display the information related to SE Linux.